# Running `docker run` from bash script fails. Command does not fail on Command Line

Tags: bash, docker

If I run the following from the command line.

```
docker run -t repo:tag ls -l
```

the command succeeds just fine. However, if I invoke the same from within a bash script I get the following ERROR:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls
>   -l\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

What about the bash script causes this error?

Comment: Without seeing the exact invocation of the script, I'd say that you're incorrectly quoting the arguments so that `"ls" "-l"` has become `"ls -l"`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `-t` flag when running in the bash script?

Comment: @DanFarrell yes "ls" "-l" was being treated as "ls -l". Please put this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "exec: \"ls -l\": executable file not found in $PATH"

From the error I can tell that when you invoke docker, you somehow invoke with `ls -l` including space as one argument.  Something like,

```
docker run -t repo:tag "ls -l" # wrong
```

or perhaps

```
cmd="ls -l" 
docker run -t repo:tag "$cmd" # wrong
```

The shell to parse the docker command must see `ls` and `-l` as separate parameters so that the argument `-l` is distinguished from the `ls` executable name.

```
cmd="ls -l" 
docker run -t repo:tag $cmd #works
```